# Align two divs (on top of each other) next to one div

Tags: html

I am trying to create a testimonials page with an image to the left, then to the right have a set of stacked "divs".  Right now it appears as if they are all being lined up in-line block style.

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ribbs2521/GDXMZ/1/) of my issue.
I am very, very new to HTML so I apologize if this is a simple fix.

Oh, and sorry I said aligning divs when it technically isn't dealing with divs that is my problem but I wasn't sure how else to explain it.

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <img src="" width="200" height="200">
                <blockquote>
                    This is a testimonial, Normally there would be a quote icon in the upper left but this is just a sample.  Anyway, that's the reason for the padding.
                </blockquote>
                <cite>
                    <strong>Name</strong> | <span>Business</span>
                </cite>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.container {
    width: 960px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.content {
    padding: 10px 0;
}
ul {
    padding: 0 15px 15px 40px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
ul li {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
img {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
blockquote {
    background-image: url(images/icon_quote.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-left: 35px;
    width: 450px;
    float: left;
}
cite {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 0 0 45px;
    list-style: none;   
}
span {
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #777 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just wrap your right content with one div and remove float from `blockquote` and `cite`

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GDXMZ/2/)

hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: Ahh, thank you, all these divs and wrapping of divs can get very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your corrected [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GDXMZ/6/). Following css corrected.

```
img {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-right:30px;
}
blockquote {
    background-image: url(images/icon_quote.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /*margin-left: 30px;*/
    padding-left: 35px;
    width: 450px;
    /*float: left;*/
}
cite {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0px;
    list-style: none;   
}
```